# Installing laravel on a new device with XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am trying to create a new project on a new fresh terminal with Windows 10. I am using PHP version 8.2.9. I installed XAMPP, and also composer. However, every time I try to create a new project in Laravel, I get this error:

`Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping. The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php 8.2.9\php.ini Now trying to download from source`

I understand the answer lies inside of the php.ini file. I could not find the original

extension=zip,

so I added it in

I also added extension=gd

I even ran composer diagnose, and everything checked out until the end. Here is the list of what is displayed on my terminal:

````
PHP version: 8.2.9
PHP binary path: C:\php 8.2.9\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
cURL version: 7.85.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/3.0.8
zip: extension not loaded, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available```
````

Comment: restart your apache

Comment: I uninstalled apache and rebooted everything. I added in the file path for 7-Zip, and it's saying its there. The main issue is the fact that the zip:extension is not loaded, and thus, unzip is not available